# How to access to a function in a specific js file from navigation Bar in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to access to a function in a specific js(chat.js in my local) file from the nagivation Bar in React Native.

Naviagation Bar is stated in index.ios.js and the code is given below.

```
render() {
     ....
    <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'Log In Page', index: 0, component: FirstPage }}

        configureScene={() => {
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }}

    navigationBar={
      <Navigator.NavigationBar
        routeMapper={{
            LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
            {
              if (route.index === 0) {
                return null;
              } else {
                return (
                  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigator.pop()}>
                    <Text style={styles.route_title}> Back </Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
                );
              }
            },

            RightButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
            {
              if (route.index === 10000){
                return (<Text>Done</Text>);
              }else{
                return null;
              }
            },   

            Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
              { return (<Text style={styles.route_title}> {route.title} </Text>); },
          }}
        style={{backgroundColor: '#28b496'}} />
    }
 ...
```

When I click 'back' in the page(chat.js), I want to execute a specific function that is stated in chat.js file, such as `pusher.unsubscribe('test_channel');`.

How would I be able to access an internal function from the top in React-native?
I'm looking forward to seeing any opinion on this matter!

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export this function
then import it in your index file

Comment: Hi! Stereodenis! As you suggested, I created function "exp_test()" inside chat.js (exp_test(){ pusher.unsubscribe('test_channel').

Comment: And I stated var Chat = require('./Chat'); inside index.ios.js file and call function as Chat.exp_test(). However I got an error "Chat.exp_test() is not a function." Maybe exporting part is missing. Would you give me a bit more suggestion? (:~ I strongly appreciate any idea!

Comment: look at this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: is it solves your problem? mark my answer for others

Comment: Thanks for your solution! (:

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you can use 'navigator' parameter. You can access component's functions through this parameter. You can access it by using structure below

First write a method in Navigator component

```
 <Navigator initialRoute =  {{name:'home'}}
       renderScene  =  {this.renderScene.bind(this)} 
       navigationBar = {<Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} style={styles.navBar}/>}
       callerFunction=   {() => this.yourFunctionName()} // this is what you should add
                />
```

then assign this method the function you want to call

then you can access yourFunction through this callBack function(callerFunction).

```
{navigator.props.callerFunction()}
```

Definetely you can send parameters as well.

Comment: Hi, Burak, would you let me know what 'this' hear refers? And do I have to state navigator in chat.js or not? And also, my case is to click 'leftButton'.  It seems it's not stated which button is related with caller function. How does my code know this? And my initialRoute is FirstPage.js, not chat.js. I want to make leftButton to call some function stated inside Chat.js for instance. Would you give me a bit more idea? (:

Comment: 'this' is used to call functions in classes. Probably it has the same function as it is used with other programing languages.(ref to class).2) 2)No you shouldn't have navigator component in chat.js just a reference is necessary(this.props.navigator). 3)I'm not sure about this question. Since navbarRouteMapper is in firstPage.js you can access its ref but I don't know how you can or should access chat.js ref from leftButton. Since leftbutton is usually used for pop() it will lose chat.js ref.