# How to access a function or method of js file from navigationBar in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

I want to call a function called 'test()' that is stated inside Main.js. Especially test() function will update the state of somestate inside Main.js and I put console log to see what's going on.

When the index of route is 1, as stated the below, the leftButton configuration(that is done in index.ios.js) is applied ( so it becomes 'click!' ). When I click this, then an error message is displayed, saying, Main.test is not a function.

Is there way that I can access test() function inside Main.js when clicking 'leftButton' in the navigator while staying in Main.js?

Do I have to do something inside index.ios.js or inside Main.js? Please share any idea with me!! (:

The below is snippet of my code ( both index.ios.js and Main.js )

***////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////***

```
...
var Main = require('./Main');
...
render() {

    return (
        <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'Log In Page', index: 0, component: FirstPage }}
        configureScene={() => {
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }}

        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={{
              LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
              {
                if (route.index === 0) {
                  return null;
                } else if(route.index ===1) {
                  return (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>  {  Main.test()  } } >
                        <View style={styles.back}>
                          <Text>click!</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  );  
                } else{
                  return (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {navigator.pop();     console.log('ended..'); }}>
                      <View style={styles.back}>
                        <Text>Click</Text>
                      </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  );
                }
              },

              Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) =>
                { return (<Text style={styles.route_title}> {route.title} {route.index} </Text>); },
            }}
          style={{backgroundColor: '#28b496'}} />
        }

        renderScene={(route, navigator) => React.createElement(route.component, { ...route.passProps, navigator })}
        style={{padding: 0}}  />

      );

  }
```

***////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////***

```
..

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ..
  }

  test(){
   console.log('I wish this will be triggered!');
   console.log('This is the function that I want to call');
   this.setState({
     somestate: 'change to this man'
   });
  }

  render(){
     return(
     <Text>HI</Text>
     );
  }

...
module.exports = Main;
```

***////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910069/how-to-access-to-a-function-in-a-specific-js-file-from-navigation-bar-in-react-n/38936079#38936079

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `Main` is a React component - in that case you cannot call test method directly unless you instantiate that component and access a reference to it (e.g. `this.refs.main.test()`).

I'd strongly suggest extracting test method out so that it's not component specific or making it static.

In case none of the above are possible, you could try rendering `Main` in below the `<Navigator />` and using refs:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
       <Navigator />
       <Main ref="main" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and accessing the method using refs as proposed at the beginning of the answer.

However, if your `Main` component is already in the tree (e.g. it's your `parent` component), you could use `context` and pass the method as a part of it.

Comment: Hi! Mike! THanks for your suggestion. I tried rendering Main n below using refs, but I encountered other errors since Main.js receives props from the previous Page, meaning it can't be open from the beginning. I want to understand your final suggestion. For me index.ios.js is the top js with Navigator component. Initial route is FirstPage.js. Then it goes to Main.js. In that situation, how I can use context and pass the method as a part of "it(?)"  My end goal is to access test() from index.io.js with the current code or totally change the structure to enable this! Please give me any hunch!!